# Issues calling Backbone view functions from other functions

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-views

I'm trying to call a few functions when the window is resized. The changePosition function is called just fine, but the tryPrint function is suffering from a "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'tryPrint'" error. I don't understand why this is the case. I tried adding a "this" parameter into the resize listener but that didn't lead me anywhere...

```
class App.Views.Pages.WorkView extends Backbone.View

  template: JST["backbone/templates/pages/work"]

  initialize: () ->
    this.render()
    $(window).on('resize', this.changePosition)

  tryPrint: ->
    console.log("TRYING")

  changePosition: ->
    this.tryPrint()

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template())
    return this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `this` (AKA `@` in CoffeeScript) inside a function depends on how the function is called unless you've bound the function to a specific object. You're doing this to bind the function to an event:

```
$(window).on('resize', this.changePosition)
```

jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will set `this` to `window` when calling `changePosition` in this case:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events this is an element matching `selector`.

If you want `this` to be the view then use a [fat-arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) when defining the method:

```
changePosition: =>
    @tryPrint()
```

Other options:

1. Use a bound function:

   ```
   $(window).on('resize', @changePosition.bind(@))
   $(window).on('resize', _(@changePosition).bind(@))
   $(window).on('resize', $.proxy(@changePosition, @))
   #...
   ```
2. Manually set `this`:

   ```
   that = @
   $(window).on('resize', -> that.changePosition())
   ```

Using `=>` is probably the easiest as you'll want to [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the handler when destroying your view and `=>` will keep function references right.

Comment: I had no idea that fat arrows made a difference at all. I really appreciate it!